# Difference between modelling dependent var given 2 independent vars and model where 1 independent var has been combined with the dependent var

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Imagine that we have an exam result dataset involving gender and exam results. I want to work out the impact of gender on exam results using the following model (which controls for student 'ability' by adding performance in other subjects):

```
Outcome in subject X ~ Gender + Average results in other subjects
```

How is this different from:

```
Difference between X and other subjects ~ Gender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your modelling goals:

- if you are thinking of causal inference then in the first model, you are either estimating the effect of the average results in other subjects while controlling for the possible confounder (or competing exposure) Gender; or you are estimating the effect of Gender on the outcome, while controlling for the possible confounder (or competing exposure) of average results in other subjects. In the 2nd model you are estimating the effect of Gender on the difference in results
- if you are only interested in prediction, then you are predicting different things, although it is easy to see that the predictions in both models are related, so you could argue that they are essentially the same.